# Let X be a space and C a collection of connected subsets of X

Tags: general-topology

[image]

This is the problem. I am having a hard time showing that the union of $C$ and then its union of D is connected. I know that I am supposed to bring two open sets (say U and V), s.t. their union will not give X and their intersection will not give an empty set as per definition of connected spaces.

In this case, my U is $\cup C$ and V is $D$, right?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You wrote "In this case, my U is $\cup C$ and V is $D$, right?" Nope. You have to consider *any* pair of open subsets $U,V \subset X$ which satisfy the properties that $U \cup V$ contains the subset $(\cup \mathcal C) \cup D$ and that $U$ is not disjoint from that subset, and that $V$ is not disjoint from that subset. And then using only those properties, you have to derive a contradiction.

Comment: Corollary: If every $C\in \mathcal C$ is connected  and $\cap \mathcal C\ne \emptyset$ then $\cup \mathcal C$ is connected. Proof: Let $D=\{d\}$ with $d\in \cap \mathcal C.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite. Let
$$E = \left(\bigcup \mathcal{C}\right) \cup D.$$
We say $E$ is disconnected if there are two disjoint, relatively open, non-empty subsets of $E$ that union to give $E$. That is, there are open $U, V$ so that $U \cap E$ and $V \cap E$ are non-empty, $U \cap V \cap E = \emptyset$, and
$$E = (U \cap E) \cup (V \cap E) \iff E \subseteq U \cup V.$$
Now, for the sake of contradiction, suppose such sets exist. Then $D \subseteq U \cup V$ and $C \subseteq U \cup V$ for all $C \in\mathcal{C}$. We also have
$$U \cap V \cap D \subseteq U \cap V \cap E = \emptyset,$$
and similarly for $C \in \mathcal{C}$.

But, $D$ and $C \in \mathcal{C}$ are connected, so we must have $U \cap D = \emptyset$ (which implies $D \subseteq V$) or $V \cap D = \emptyset$ (i.e. $D \subseteq U$), and similarly for $C \in \mathcal{C}$. That is, $D$ and each $C \in \mathcal{C}$ must lie in one open set or the other.

Now, assume without loss of generality that $D \subseteq U$ (and $D \cap V = \emptyset$). Note that, for any $C \in \mathcal{C}$, we have $D \cap C \neq \emptyset$, hence
$$C \cap U \supseteq C \cap D \neq \emptyset,$$
hence we must have $C \subseteq U$ instead of $V$. This holds for all $C \in \mathcal{C}$, hence,
$$E \subseteq U \implies E \cap V = \emptyset,$$
i.e. one of our relatively open subsets of $E$ is actually empty, against assumption. Thus, $E$ is connected.

Comment: thanks a lot, can you pls explain how you got E=(U∩E)∪(V∩E) ?

Comment: We need our relatively open subsets $U \cap E$ and $V \cap E$ to union to give the whole subspace $E$.

Comment: ok, so I can say Y=(Y∩U)∪(Y∩V)? Also, C=(C∩U)∪(C∩V)? Here, (Y∩U) and (Y∩V) are open subsets so when you take their union you get the whole subspace. right? Can you tell me which theorem or proposition is this? It would be great if you can send a link for this.

Comment: Not in general, but you can say this when $Y$ is a subset of $U \cup V$. Try drawing a Venn diagram of the situation. If $Y$ is completely contained in $U \cup V$, then $Y$ is the union of these intersections. So, if $Y = E$, or any subset of $E$ like $D$ or $C \in \mathcal{C}$, we get equality.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly know that a space $Y$ is connected if and only if each continuos map $f : Y \to 2$ is constant. Here $2 = \{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology.

So let $f : E = (\bigcup C) \cup D \to 2$ be continuous. Then $f \mid_D$ is constant since $D$ is connected. Thus $f(x) = a_D \in 2$ for all $x \in D$. Similarly all $f \mid_C$ are constant. Thus $f(x) = a_C$ for all $x \in C$. But we know that $C \cap D \ne \emptyset$, thus for $x \in C \cap D$ we have $a_D = f(x) = a_C$. This shows that $f(x) = a_D$ for all $x \in E$.

Comment: Nice example of how an equivalent "external" condition ( the function $f$) can streamline an argument.